# Facebook - Music, Books, Interests.. are they all included in "Likes"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of users' interests. So I am making calls to the graph api to retrieve things like books, music, etc. It seems everything under "Likes" also includes everything listed under books, music, etc. Are their any exceptions, or can I just make one call to retrieve Likes?

Answer (score 3):

As you can find it on the [API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), the "Likes" retrieve "All the pages this user has liked". You need the permission user_likes.

You just need to do the following request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/ID/likes?access_token=TOKEN
```

where ID is the ID of the user and TOKEN is the token that you have received.

It will return An array of JSON objects containing like id, name, category and create_time fields.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The facebook Likes api for the graph includes: likes, share counts, comments and notes. You can make one call to retrieve all likes, but it is not just limited to likes, they could have put a comment on the page describing that they didn't like it, and it will still show up here.